# Minimum lock-in period for ULIP to avail tax benefit

Tags: taxes, india

What is the minimum lock-in period in ULIP to avail tax benefit in India.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum lock-in period for ULIP to avail tax benefit.

However most of the Insurance companies have a lock-in for 3 to 5 years for normal closure of the policy. Before this period, there are surrender charges apart from higher premium allocation charges in the first 2 years. So if you are planning to buy an ULIP, get the tax benefit and close; then you will actually be loosing more money then the tax benefit you would stand to gain.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to take benefit u/s 80C. In case of ULIP of UTI or LIC Mutual Fund, minimum period of holding is 5 years.

In case of other insurance premium period of holding is 2 years.

Refer Page A-229 of Direct Tax Ready Reckoner by Taxman